# Why declare the class that you included as a header file?

Tags: c++

Why declare the class that you included as a header file?

```
#include "TreeCallObj.h"
#include "TreeDevObj.h"
#include "TreeDevCallObj.h"

class TreeCallObj; //what is the purpose of this line ?
class TreeDevObj;  //what is the purpose of this line ?
class TreeDevCallObj;  //what is the purpose of this line ?


class Apple
{
public:
...
private:
...
}
```

Comment: Seems like we're missing some context. Possibly there's some circular header file referencing going on, and the `TreeWhateverObj` classes are referred to by pointer only in the current file? Maybe it was just written by someone who really likes their forward definitions. Suffixing class names in `Obj` seems like a crazy coding convention alert to me.

Comment: I have read that declaring the class may improve compile time if the project takes 10 minutes to build?  I don't know how true this is and how much benefit either.

Comment: Sounds pretty unlikely, but also fairly straightforward to test. Let us know how it goes ;-)

Comment: @jdl: Declaring the class *instead of* including its definition might (or might not) improve compile time, if you don't need the full definition. Redundantly declaring it *in addition to* its definition won't improve anything.

Comment: When I commented those lines out, I didn't see any improvement in build time.  I don't know if there is a scenerio where it may make a difference?

Comment: @jdl: If you don't include the headers at all, then there might be an improvement. That's only possible if you don't need the full class definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
//a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"
class A
{
   B* b;
};
#endif

//b.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"
class B
{
   A* a;
};
#endif
```

Now you try to include one of the files in a different one, say you `#include "a.h"`.

The compiler will parse it as:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
```

fine - `A_H` isn't defined

```
#include "b.h"
```

try to paste the contents:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
```

ok, since `B_H` isn't defined

```
#include "a.h"
```

this will not define `A`, because `A_H` is defined. So next, we have

```
class B
{
   A* a;
};
```

which will lead to an error, because `A` wasn't defined or declared before the use.

The forward declaration fixes this.

**Of course**, the best solution to this is to not include at all (unless you absolutely have to).

Comment: No. If in the third case `A_H` has already been defined, then class `A` would have already been defined too for that same scope.

Comment: @EitanT no, because A.h includes B.h before A is defined. Right?

Comment: "this will not define A, because A_H is defined. So next, we have" - yes, and that's the point of the include guards. If `A_H` is defined, then the A class is already declared - no error.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore oh yes! Sorry for the ignorance, you're right. +1.

Comment: Ah yes, it's because of the circular dependency -- now I see where my thought process has gone wrong... +1 for the example.

Comment: @EitanT yes, circular dependencies suck. I always use forward declarations where possible.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the purpose of this line?

Ideally nothing. It's superfluous.

However, as @Luchian Grigore pointed out, there may be such a badly-designed code that due to the incorrect use of include guards and cross-includes, the forward declarations may be necessary.

Comment: I don't it necessarily is badly-designed code. It's just circular dependency.

Comment: @EitanT Well, I think it is. If one's unable to solve a problem without cross-referencing, there's a problem in design. Could you please provide an example where you think it's a good approach to follow?

Comment: Suppose that you have class `Daddy` with pointers to a class `Son`, and class `Son` needs to invoke a function in class `Daddy`.

Comment: You'll get this wherever a sub-class needs to "know" about the parent class. What's wrong about it?

Comment: @EitanT no. It's not a subclass and its superclass. It's about two different classes, of which one contains the other. But this always can be rewritten by making the container object calling the contained one. If there's a subclass, it easily can access its superclass' methods, since if a class (subclass) inherits from another (superclass), then in order to use/declare the subclass, you must already have defined the superclass.

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong word, but by "sub-class" I meant to describe a contained class, and by "parent" I meant the container class, without any reference to inheritance.

Comment: @EitanT I see, yes, that's another word.

Answer (score 3):

If in files there is definition of classes, so, `forward declaration` is unnecessary in normal cases.

Answer (score 1):

No reason at all. You need to do one or the other, depending on the situation, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, there's no need.

However, this may have evolved historically: At some point, an incomplete type may have been enough:

```
class Foo;

struct Gizmo
{
    void f(Foo);
};
```

Then, at a later point, the author decided she needed the complete type:

```
#include "Foo.hpp"

class Foo;

struct Gizmo
{
    void f(Foo);
    Foo x;
};
```

The original code may just have been amended with the now-necessary header inclusion...

Comment: Or, `struct Gizmo { Foo *foo; }` which is later changed to `struct Gizmo { Foo foo; }`. So for the former, a declaration `class Foo;` is  enough, but for the latter the definition is needed hence `#include "foo.hpp"`. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes! But I didn't want to suggest to anyone that `Foo*` is acceptable C++ :-) I was momentarily toying with `unique_ptr<Foo[]>`...

Comment: When you talk about *historically*, then you can talk about `Foo*` *comfortably* ;-).  Nobody will downvote you :P (Well, not at least me).

Comment: @Nawaz: Haha, no, not historically regarding C++, but historically in the personal development history of the astute C++11 programmer's project!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess there's some history to this. Orginally the coder tried not to include the header files and used forward declarations instead. Then as the code expanded they found they needed the header files after all, but didn't bother to deleted the forward declarations.

As others have said there's no purpose to having a forward declaration after the class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that your header does not have guards against multiple inclusion. Also it is possible that some of the included other headers (headers usually have such guards) included that header back. As result it did not compile. So someone added forward declarations to fix the wrong bug.

Answer (score 0):

If your header files are correct i see no point in declaring because they should already declared in header